# TypeScript Error - Cannot find module 'stytch' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) tags

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, stytch

I'm working on a Next.js application and trying to import the 'stytch' module in TypeScript. However, I'm running into an issue where TypeScript is unable to find the module or its type declarations. The error message is:

```
Cannot find module 'stytch' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Here's the TypeScript code where the error is occurring:

```js
import * as stytch from 'stytch';

let client;

const loadStytch = () => {
  if (!client) {
    client = new stytch.Client({
      project_id: process.env.STYTCH_PROJECT_ID || "",
      secret: process.env.STYTCH_SECRET || "",
      env:
        process.env.STYTCH_PROJECT_ENV === "live"
          ? stytch.envs.live
          : stytch.envs.test,
    });
  }

  return client;
};

export default loadStytch;
```

This code is located in a file called `loadStytch.tsx`.

I have the 'stytch' module installed in my project and it is at version "^5.18.1", as confirmed by running `npm list stytch`.

The 'stytch' module has a type declaration file at `node_modules\stytch ypes\lib\client.d.ts`.

```js
/// <reference types="node" />
import * as http from "http";
import { CryptoWallets } from "./crypto_wallets";
import { MagicLinks } from "./magic_links";
import { OAuth } from "./oauth";
import { OTPs } from "./otps";
import { Passwords } from "./passwords";
import { Sessions } from "./sessions";
import { TOTPs } from "./totps";
import { Users } from "./users";
import { WebAuthn } from "./webauthn";
interface Config {
    project_id: string;
    secret: string;
    env: string;
    timeout?: number;
    agent?: http.Agent;
}
export declare class Client {
    users: Users;
    magicLinks: MagicLinks;
    otps: OTPs;
    oauth: OAuth;
    passwords: Passwords;
    sessions: Sessions;
    totps: TOTPs;
    webauthn: WebAuthn;
    cryptoWallets: CryptoWallets;
    private fetchConfig;
    constructor(config: Config);
}
export {};
```

Despite all of this, I'm still getting the error. I've tried running `npm install` to make sure all dependencies are installed, but the error persists.

```
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

`import * as stytch from 'stytch';`

with `const stytch = require("stytch");`

Comment: npm install --save-dev @types/stytch
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fstytch - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/stytch@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR!